# Convert edge_constrained_map to vertex_constrained_map

Tags: cgal

I have been trying to find if there is a function that allows to go from an edge_is_constrained_map to a vertex_is_constrained_map but found none so far. Is there some build in functionality for this in CGAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wrapper and query on the fly the edge property map, but except if you really care about memory usage more, I would recommend just making another vertex property map and filling it based on your edge property map:

```cpp
  ecm = ...; // the "constrained edges" property map (edge_descriptor -> bool)
  vcm = ...; // the "constrained vertices" property map (vertex_descriptor -> bool)

  for(edge_descriptor e : edges(g))
  {
    if(get(ecm, e)
    {
      put(vcm, source(e, g), true);
      put(vcm, target(e, g), true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: For the time the being creating another vertex property map should suffice, but in eventually I will have to make use of a wrapper so will also look further into how  to implement that option. Thank you!

Comment: Some useful blocks for the wrapper: [examples of property maps](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Property_map/include/CGAL/property_map.h); [`halfedges_around_target(vertex, graph)`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIterators.html#ga2be4fd4d24b1e48e00a92f90f0f2923c). Your wrapper around the edge constrained property map (`ecm`) will thus have an operator `get(wrapper_pmap, vertex_descriptor)` and within that `get`, check the incident halfedges, convert to edge (with the function `edge(halfedge_descriptor, graph)`), and check `ecm`.